# SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal - setTimeout or concatenation?

Tags: javascript, concatenation, settimeout

I have a problem with a single line in my JS code:

```
window.setTimeout('window.location.href = "http://holy-war.net/town/alchemist/?w="' + world + ';',2000);
```

Where world is a string containing the text "4IN" (no quotes).Perhaps my concatenation is broken there somehow, or perhaps you can't even pass a variable into the setTimeout function? Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your concatenation is broken. It will produce the code

```
window.location.href = "http://holy-war.net/town/alchemist/?w="4IN;
//                                                             ^^^
```

which exhibits exactly the problem that the error message describes. Instead:

- Fix the quote

  ```
  window.setTimeout('window.location.href = "http://holy-war.net/town/alchemist/?w=' + world + '";', 2000);
  ```
- Use proper serialisation

  ```
  window.setTimeout('window.location.href = '+JSON.stringify('http://holy-war.net/town/alchemist/?w=' + world) + ';', 2000);
  ```
- Don't generate code to `eval` at all, use a function as you're supposed to!

  ```
  window.setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = 'http://holy-war.net/town/alchemist/?w=' + world;
  }, 2000);
  ```

Comment: Oh I just realized how dumb I was, lol. But if I had noticed, I wouldn't have known to use function in settimeout, so I guess there's good in bad after all x)

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`. Use a function instead:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = "http://holy-war.net/town/alchemist/?w=" + world;
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Will start implementing functions into setTimeout from now on instead.